# Pdfium save PDF document incremental

Tags: c++, .net, save, pdfium

The FPDF_INCREMENTAL=1 flag in the FPDF_SaveAsCopy function does not work. Generates an incorrect PDF document.

Using 0 (zero) instead of FPDF_INCREMENTAL, it works. But I would like to save incrementally, using 0 does not save incrementally.

How to make the FPDF_INCREMENTAL flag work? Do I need to enable anything?

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/T_Patagames_Pdf_Enums_SaveFlags.htm) that the Flag for the incremental save is '1'.

```
 FPDF_SaveAsCopy(IntPtr, FPDF_FILEWRITE, SaveFlags)
```

Comment: Using FPDF_INCREMENTAL = 1 Generates an incorrect PDF document. I don't think it has that functionality. Despite having the flag it does not work.